# Alternative way to remember wifi networks

Tags: wireless-networking

It seems to me (correct me if I'm wrong), that laptops and other wireless devices remember wireless networks based on the network name. Because of this, if I connect to one network, called "linksys" for example, then my devices will automatically connect to other networks with this same name. Is there some way to prevent this? Is there a more distinguishing feature of wireless networks that my devices can use to keep track of what which networks I have used in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some way to prevent this?

Yes by using authentication that requires a password and/or security keys.

> Is there a more distinguishing feature of wireless networks that my devices can use to keep track of what which networks I have used in the past?

Perhaps, the best bet would probably be to track the MAC address of the WiFi Access Points are you connect to them.  This is not something that's inherently done by the OS, so you'll need to setup  some form of logging that records the MAC on connection to a WiFi network.

Comment: I deleted my comment, I don't have enough hardware to test and can't  find a web reference either.